# Jquery - reusable checkbox function

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've run into a wall with my limited JQuery knowledge,
I'm using a number of checkboxes:

```
    <input id="e_1" class="hiders" type="checkbox">
    <label for="e_1">Hide Element 1</label>

    <input id="e_2" class="hiders" type="checkbox">
    <label for="e_2">Hide Element 2</label>

    //Currently 6 of the above, with unique id's and shared class
```

I want to create a universal (and reusable function) to hide the related divs:

```
    <div id="e_1_div"> content </div>

    <div id="e_2_div"> content </div>

    //Currently 6 of the above, with unique id's and shared class
```

The following solution is what I am using currently (individual functions for each checkbox), and my limited knowledge tells me that it is horribly malformed, and probably drains a whole lot of unnecessary power as well.

```
    $('#e_1').change(function(){
       $('#e_1_div').toggle();
    });

    $('#e_2').change(function(){
       $('#e_2_div').toggle();
    });
```

So my question: Where do I start? Where can I get to know more about creating reusable functions for something like this?
Or if you really want to spoil me, what would be a possible solution, or a hint towards it?

Thank you for your time,
Dragan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could target all of the elements at once by constructing a selector dynamically:

```
$('input[id^="e_"]').change(function() {
    $('#' + this.id + '_div').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple!, Thank you blender!

Comment: @Blender - Hey, can you please explain 'input[id^="e_"]' rule? Does ^="e_" means that it starts with e_ and can have anything after that?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at the jQuery (and CSS) [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

try this.. so that you can trigger it dynamically

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
  $(this).next('div').toggle();
});​
```

Comment: If I'm correct the current structure won't allow me to use next, because the 'control-panel' containing the checkboxes is not a sibling to the divs, forgot to specify that, sorry!

Comment: is it near the checkboxes? cause if it is you may use this you can specify element inside next() method

Comment: It's a div outside of the normal structure, on it's own z-index, the relation (controlpanel-div) would be something like grandchildren/grand-grandchildren of a sibling

Answer (score 0):

Please find below simple jquery script which will do the needful

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Toggle Checkbox</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".hiders").change(function(){
        var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        var divId = currentId+"_div";
        $("#"+divId).toggle();
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<input id="e_1" class="hiders" type="checkbox" /><label for="e_1">Hide Element 1</label>

<input id="e_2" class="hiders" type="checkbox" /><label for="e_2">Hide Element 2</label>

<div id="e_1_div">element - 1</div>

<div id="e_2_div">element - 2</div>

</body>
</html>
```